# Cookies are not set in browser in SPA to API communication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, axios, cross-domain, csrf

I am setting up React SPA (www.mysite.com) and Rails API (api.mysite.com) app. When I use same URL name everything works as expected, however when URL names are different, the web browser is not setting site cookie. With cookies missing, CSRF validation also fails of course. So for example if SPA App runs on `localhost` and Rails API App on `localhost:3000` all good, the problem is only when I use the intended DNS names.

Sounds like a CORS problem but I can’t find where for many days now…

Here is my config:

Rails side I am using `rack-cors` ruby gem

> config/initializers/cors.rb

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
   allow do
     origins 'localhost’,  'www.mysite.com',

     resource '*',
       headers: :any,
       credentials: true,
       methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
   end
end

Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = false
```

on React side I have `axios` config as follows:

> src/App.js

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "CSRF-TOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRF-Token";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

When React App starts, it makes a `GET` request to the API backend to grab CSRF token for later use. In the same time browser is supposed to set site cookies.

```
    axios
        .get("/sessions/csrf_token", {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
        })
        .then(response => {
          // do stuff
          });
        });
```

The response headers look the same in both cases when site cookies are set and missing

[image]

I can also see cookies are sent to the browser and yet they are missing under Cookies section

[image]

Any thoughts on what I can be missing here are very much appreciated!!!
Thanks!!

> UPDATE:

I also should have mentioned that my session config file is set to allow subdomains

> config/initializers/session_store.rb

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_mysite_session', expire_after: 8.hours, domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Possibly something else is wrong with my cookies config, but I can't figure out where to look at and what other settings should be checked.

Here is a screenshot of my Cookies pane when I use `localhost` and cookies are retained in the browser as expected:

[image]

When I use `www.mysite.com` and `api.mysite.com` names, the pane on the right is just empty.

Comment: This is somewhat of a shot in the dark but have you tried specifying the second domain without the WWW in your rack-cors config? Also is there anyway we could get a picture of your browser cookies pane and of the source code with those real domains you were talking about?

Comment: @sevensidedmarble I've tried domain without www to no success. In general if CORS settings are misconfigured in any way, axios simply doesn't get a back a valid response. In my case I see no error and API call returns a valid JSON response. The only problem is my cookies pane is empty. Let me add an update to the post itself with a screenshot of what I expect the cookies pane to look like

Comment: I think I may have figured it out, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into this and I think this may be relevant to what you're seeing:

[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Apparently if you don't specify a domain in the `set-cookie` header, the cookie is considered "host only". So you might have to have it look like:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=mydomain.com
```

I'm sure this is doable with Axios.

Comment: So my problem is Rails doesn't send domain information with cookies. This should be handled by  Rails.application.config.session_store line from above, but it is not happening for some reason. I can manually set custom cookie with the domain attribute and then it appears in Cookies pane. Now I need to figure out why Rails doesn't do it globally... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I fixed this, setting a domain for cookies.

In ApplicationController, when you set CSRF-TOKEN do the follows

```
cookies["CSRF-TOKEN"] = {
  value: form_authenticity_token,
  domain: ".mysite.com"
}
```

And in config/application.rb add the domain too
`config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, domain: ".mysite.com"`

I hope that this answer helps you